# sorting numbers in an expression in input

Tags: string, sorting, input

I want to sort the numbers that I get through the input method.
I've tried many codes so far but none of them works.
my input is: 3+2+1
my desired output: 1+2+3
I just need these three numbers in order
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to confirm - your input is a string `3+2+1`?

Comment: in what language?

Comment: I got my answer dear WBM, but I wanted it in python anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you already have your `input string` - `3+2+1`, then you can do:

```py
s = `3+2+1`.split('+')  # ['3', '2', '1']
n = sorted(s, key=int)  # ['1', '2', '3']  The you can proceed to do next...
```

Comment: Thank you, Daniel.I really appreciate that

Comment: Glad that I can help. Keep learning...

Comment: sure, let's go...